# Using Repeater to print out buttons and images in a table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I'm trying to develop a shopping cart for a website for a class project.

Initially, I had a webpage query a DB for all the appropriate products, then I created a loop that'd parse out those results, and store a label's text to be the HTML for the thumbnails in a table. I tried adding a "Add To Cart" button to this loop and it wasn't working, then I quickly learned this is completely the wrong way to go about this problem.

I was directed towards the Repeater control to just repeat a row of products and the button, but I can't make much sense of any of the examples I've seen online.

Could someone try to explain how I'd use the Repeater to print out different buttons and images in a table?

Thanks. Oh, and this is C# / .NET 4.0

Comment: I'm sorry; didn't realize there was a homework tag. it's an on-going project we've been working on for the whole quarter.

Comment: No worries. Just remember it in the future or you'll risk upsetting to SO gods...

Comment: why not using gridview and boundcontrols to link to that dataset you retrieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm gonna have to guess as some of the field names in your data, but hopefully you can follow this:

```xml
<table>
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="ProductList" DataSource=" ... ">
   <ItemTemplate>
       <tr><td><img title='<%# Eval("ProductName")%> thumbnail' href='images/producthumbnails/<%# Eval("ProductID")%>.jpg' /></td>
           <td><%#Eval("ProductName")%></td>
           <td><asp:Button runat="server" id="btnAddToCart" OnCommand="AddToCart_Click" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ProductID")%>' /></td>
       </tr>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</table>
```